# How to close "holes" in objects such as sheet metal?

Tags: python

[image: image of sheet metal with several holes for screws and nuts]

[image]

Question
I want to use some blender functionality to close these holes in mesh objects and remove the vertices. I have alot hence i need to automate the process. Im scripting my way about through the Python API. I cant seem to find any function in Blender I can call to do this. I'm not smart enough to develop a "hole detection"-algorithm myself. Does anyone know how to solve this or could point me in the right direction, then I would be pleased :)

Why? (Background)
Because they are small non-important details, that have a lot of triangles in them.
I use the model in an industrial 3d application, so they have to be optimized from their original format to run on all kinds of hardware. Sometimes my scenes(unity) have several hundred or even thousands of models displayed at the same time.

Desired result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question is still active but I think I can offer you a solution.
If these are all the same meshes, a quick way would be to put them into a collection and have a desired model made by hand and replace them with the model by looping over that collection. Or you can look at the `fill_holes()` api and plug in the sides if you know and then perform a non manifold vert select and dissolve them.

Or another would be look at the boundary loop method and invert that selection and dissolve delete.

PS: blender noobie but looking at those methods and trialing what will select them may help you and just look at the info console when you find something that works as that will at least point you in the direction for the automation side
And try [OpenAI](https://openai.com/). The code is poor for Blender but it can point you on the right track and tweak it to work.